# Run Hadoop cluster only from masrer node windows 10

Tags: hadoop

I Have hadoop 3.2.1 cluster running on 3 windows 10 home, with a master node and 2 slave nodes. whenever i want to start the nodes i have to start each one individually by running "start-all.cmd".
is there a way that i can just run the master node and it will start the other nodes by it self ?

Answer (score 0):

`start-all` only refers to all processes on one machine.

If you want a centralized way to start all components of multiple servers, use a tool like Apache Ambari.